# Rajya sabha member and Election in India

Tags: election, india

How is rajya sabha member elected ? What is the process of Rajya Sabha election?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest answer is the member is elected by the representatives of the state assemblies (the MLAs - Member of the Legislative Assembly of individual states). And 12 are directly appointed by the President of India (the 12 should be knowledgeably in their area of expertise - arts, social service, etc).

Long answer: [Check this out](http://rajyasabha.nic.in/rsnew/about_parliament/rajya_sabha_introduction.asp)